# How to hardcode password in batch file

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, passwords

I am creating a batch file that will automatically run the following commands:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin
initdb -D "data" -U USERNAME –E UTF-8
pg_ctl -D "data" -l logfile start
createdb -E UTF-8 -e -O USERNAME -U USERNAME -w sampledb
```

When I get to this point, it prompts for a password -- is there a way I can hardcode this password in, so I don't have to manually enter it in?

Thanks! Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: if you simply type 'createdb' does it show you the flags that you can pass in?  I know in mysql you can pass a -p'password' without the ' and it will do the password for you.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html

Answer (score 3):

You can specify `PGPASSWORD` as an environment variable for many commands, e.g:

```
PGPASSWORD=foo pg_...
```